# 403 invalid signature laravel email verification after using queue

Tags: php, laravel, jobs, laravel-queue

When i configure verify `email` that comes from `laravel` but after edit it to work with 
laravel `queue` it gives me this **error**

my edit: overwrite `sendEmailVerificationNotification` method in the user model

```
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    VerifyEmail::dispatch($this);
}
```

then i create a new job called  `VerifyEmail`

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail as VerifyEmailNotification;

class VerifyEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $user;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->user->notify(new VerifyEmailNotification);
    }
}
```

so what is the problem for this error and thanks in advance

**Edit**

there is something maybe the problem here
when it runs without queue the generated **URL** contains the locale language in the **URL** 
so it works fine but in case of queue didn't generate url with the locale